# How to get jenkins host detail?

Tags: python, jenkins

I want to get Jenkins host detail,
It seems for windows its present as COMPUTERNAME env variable in "http://<your.jenkins.url>/systemInfo" URL.

But for Linux hosts, I don't see this variable present.
Is there any way that I can fetch the Jenkins host (where the Jenkins is running) using python?
don't want to use a groovy script as I want to do it w/o running any job.

Comment: You could get it from `JENKINS_URL`.

Comment: how exactly?  Do you mean reverse lookup? I am looking for some way to fetch it from the GUI somehow. @zett42

Answer (score 1):

You can use HOSTNAME from Environment Variables from http://<your.jenkins.url>/systemInfo.

Comment: I am not able to see that variable, will it be available for every Jenkins master or its some additional config is needed for that?